# Convert data and time

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Want to remove TimeZone details from date+time.(EmberJS)

Input: "2019-03-11T09:00:00.000+09:00" (GMT+9) .

Like to convert in this format "2019-03-11T09:00:00.000+00:00" (GMT+0)

Usecase:
API Returning :  `timestamp: "2019-03-11T09:00:00.000+09:00"`

UI TimeZone is : `UTC+9`

Currently UI Display: `3/11/2019 18:00`

UI should show `3/11/2019 9:00`

Comment: `new Date("2019-03-11T09:00:00.000+09:00")` will convert to your local time. from there you can convert this to UTC, but not any other time zones. well, actually, now you can in modern browsers, but this post explains all that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15141762/how-to-initialize-a-javascript-date-to-a-particular-time-zone/15171030#15171030

Comment: So you're saying you want to convert the timezone to UTC but keep the same time-of-day?

Comment: thanks Steven and Phil for quick looks at my question, I updated my query with usecase. Please help me.

Comment: Is moment.js or another library an option or do you need your own pure JS solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using [ember-moment](https://github.com/stefanpenner/ember-moment) addon

`{{moment-format '12-1995-25' 'MM/DD/YYYY' 'MM-YYYY-DD'}}`

Replace `12-1995-25` with your API returning date

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to **drop timezone** from date that you receive as a string, you just need to use regular expression to remove '+09:00' part:

```
new Date('2019-03-11T09:00:00.000+09:00'.replace(/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3})[+\-]\d{2}:\d{2}/, '$1'))
```

Or, to **replace timezone with UTC**:

```
new Date('2019-03-11T09:00:00.000+09:00'.replace(/(\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}T\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.\d{3})[+\-]\d{2}:\d{2}/, '$1+00:00'))
```

If you want to **convert between timezones** you can use [moment-timezone](http://momentjs.com/timezone/) or [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/)